# Using a persistent database in Django unittests

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, wordnet

I have a large readonly Wordnet PostgreSQL database that I'd like to use from Django unittests. Specifically, I have an app, called "wordnet", that wraps this Wordnet database. Unfortunately, the default Django unittest framework uses an empty in-memory SQLite database for all apps.

How do I use my PostgreSQL database for only the wordnet app, and no other apps, within unittests?

I'm familiar with [Django database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing), and I think they might be a solution. So I've created the following in my routers.py:

```
NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS = (
    'wordnet',
    'auth',
    'contenttypes',
)
REAL_DB = 'default'

class UseRealDBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS:
            return REAL_DB
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS:
            return REAL_DB
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS and obj2._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == REAL_DB:
            return model._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS
        elif model._meta.app_label in NEEDS_REAL_DB_APPS:
            return False
        return None
```

And my tests.py looks like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from wordnet import models as wn_models

class Tests(TestCase):

    def test_wordnet(self):
        q = wn_models.Word.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(q.count(), 86547)
```

However, when I run my unittest (e.g. `manage.py test myapp.Tests.test_wordnet`), the check still fails, returning 0 for a count of all the words, indicating it's still not using the "real" database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use real database for testing.

How about first dumping your production database: look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata)

and then loading it in test fixtures: check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)

Comment: Please re-read my question. It's a read-only database with 86k words in it, as well as additional models containing definitions and part-of-speech tags. Dumped as a compressed SQL file, it's several hundred MB in size. Have you ever tried loading a fixture that large? I have. It's not pretty. Django is not designed to handle such large volumes of data.

Comment: You could dump only part of that data. Testing should be independent of any "remote" resources. If you want live testing, why not do single view that runs "tests" on live environment?

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the most practical option. There are ways to persist the test database, but they're quite complicated. I was hoping to access everything, but I guess I can suffice with a subset. I ended up creating a custom management command to simplify the generation of my fixture.